# Can an error text in Vim be replaced by personalized text?

Tags: vim

For example, say you have

```
E385: search hit BOTTOM without match for: set
```

Can this error text be replaced with let's say,

```
Reached end of file. Sorry ol'chap, nothing found.
```

Comment: @IngoKarkat - Just wanted to find out if this is a possibility. Some messages (not the one above, but every once in a while I find some that) have meaning that is completely vague to me.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I would if I could, for self-amusement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a complete solution, you have to modify the [Vim sources](http://www.vim.org/sources.php), either by modifying the (default, English) error messages or by creating your own localization (and setting your language to it), and then compile your own Vim binary.

Without modifying Vim itself, you have to wrap the commands that can issue the error. You can then intercept and translate the error message in Vimscript, like this:

```
try
    " The original, wrapped command.
    normal! n
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E385/
    echoerr "Reached end of file. Sorry ol'chap, nothing found."
endtry
```

For searches, that would be at least the `n` / `N` commands, as well as `/`, `?`, `*`, `#`, ... Unless you have a really good reason, not worth it if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Well, just thought I'd ask and check. (You know why I'm asking this, you answered the other q. as well :)